# How to clear the stdin buffer in python when stdin is non-interactive

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do I read everything there is from the stdin buffer in python without blocking? None of the stack overflow solutions I found work as my stdin is non-interactive.

## I tried:

### tcflush

`tcflush(sys.stdin, TCIOFLUSH)` which does not work on non-interactive stdin.

### select

```
while select.select([sys.stdin], [], [], 0) == ([sys.stdin], [], []):
  sys.stdin.read(1)
```

and

```
while len(select.select([sys.stdin.fileno()], [], [], 0.0)[0])>0:
  os.read(sys.stdin.fileno(), 4096)
```

Which do not work because the condition in the `while` head is always `False`.

Any other ideas?

## Edit

To be more precise:

My code should

- do nothing if the input buffer is empty
- empty the buffer if there is something in it

So it should *never* block.

Comment: What do you mean by 'do not work'?  If select says there is nothing to be read, how to you know that there is something to be read?

Comment: @TerryJanReedy because if I put a `input()` after the `while` statement, it does not block. The `input()` also does not block if put before the `while` statement so I am pretty sure there is something in the buffer.

Comment: Are you trying this in Windows? The `select` functionality in Windows is provided by WinSock, and thus only works on sockets. See the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/select.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your suggestions so far. Apparently this was, after all, one of those strange concurrency problems.

When I set a timeout in the `select` call, it works. So it seems that the buffer really has not been filled at the moment I call the `select`.

Does not work (same as in the question):

```
while select.select([sys.stdin], [], [], 0) == ([sys.stdin], [], []):
  sys.stdin.read(1)
```

Does work:

```
while select.select([sys.stdin], [], [], 0.01) == ([sys.stdin], [], []):
  sys.stdin.read(1)
```

As the things I want to read are line-based, I can read a whole line at a time with `input` instead of reading single characters with `read` though, and then the slowdown of the timeout in the while loop will not be noticeable. (There will be max. 5-10 lines in the buffer).

I am not totally satisfied with this solution as it involves waiting for an arbitrary amount of time (will `0.01` always be enough?). But on the other hand I can't think of a better solution right now as I can't influence the code writing to "my stdin".

Answer (score 1):

You are using a zero seconds timeout in your `select()` call, which effectively makes select into a one-shot poll operation that does **not** wait until data is available.

```
while len(select.select([sys.stdin.fileno()], [], [], 0.0)[0])>0:
                                                       ^
                                                       |
                                                This means don't wait
```

Try instead:

```
while len(select.select([sys.stdin.fileno()], [], [], None)[0]) > 0:
```

Comment: Not blocking is the whole point ;-) See the clarification I just added.

Comment: But then that's because there isn't any data to read. What is `stdin` connected to?